# dropdown show right value

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, laravel-5

ve two values in my combo box. Car and bicycle when the user selects one of them it will be stored in the database with 1 or 2. But how do I make sure that when the user edits it the chosen values shows up.

For example I've saved bicycle in the database than when the user wants to edit it it must show bicycle and not car!

I'm working with laravel.

EDIT

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="content" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Standaard route</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                 @if($standaardroute->isEmpty())
                                <label>U heeft nog geen standaardroutes. Maak deze <a href="/public/createroute">hier</a> aan.</label>
                                 @else
                                <select class="form-control input-sm" name="standaardroute" id="standaardroute">
                                @foreach($standaardroute as $route)
                                    <option value="{!! $route->id !!}">{!! $route->van !!} - {!! $route->naar !!}</option>
                                @endforeach
                                </select>               
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endif
```

EDIT

I've 2 dropdown menus. When one dropdown is selected the other one should receive a number from the database and show the right value for example bicycle. When the first dropdown menu is selected it post a request and receives the values back. When I receive information back for a text box I say:

```
$("#van").val(result.van);
```

But how do I have to do this with a dropdown menu?

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var xhr;
    });

    $("#standaardroute").change(function(e) {
    csrf = $("#token").attr('content')
    option = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
          url: '/public/receiveuserinformation',
          type: 'POST',
          data: { option_id: option },
          beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrf);},
          success: function(result) {
              $("#van").val(result.van);
              //here should be something for the dropdownmenu
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you've two options in an array: `$types = array('1' => 'car', '2' => 'bicycle');` and you're saving it in products table and you've current product data in `$product` variable

```
<select>
    <?php foreach($types as $type_id => type_name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $type_id; ?>" <?php if($type_id == $product->type) echo "selected"; ?>>
            <?php echo $type_name; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

---

EDIT: if you're using blade in laravel then you could simply achieve it by doing this:

```
{!! Form::label('type', 'Type: ') !!}
{!! Form::select('type', $types !!}
```

---

EDIT2: Try this:

```
<option value="{!! $route->id !!}" {{ ($standaardroute->route == $route->id) ? 'selected':'' }}>{!! $route->van !!} - {!! $route->naar !!}</option>
```

Note: replace `$standaardroute->route` your actual variable

---

EDIT3: Put this inside your success function:

```
$('#van option').each(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('selected');
    if($(this).val() == result.van){
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
});
```

Note: I've not tested this

Comment: Oke thanks for your comment. Please see my edit. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Oke thanks that works! But what if I receive the information back with an ajax request see my edit.

Comment: Can you elaborate more

Comment: Is the second dropdown empty at first? Are the options added after user selects the first dropdown?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88946/discussion-between-gskhanal-and-jamie).

Comment: No the first dropdown is not empty at first. When selected from the second dropdown menu. The first dropdownmenu must spring to the right value that was received from the second dropdownmenu (that's a number). (The information from the second dropdown menu I receive with the ajax request.) I hope you'll understand this.